# How to run pyspark application which is egg distributed?

Tags: python-2.7, apache-spark, pyspark, egg

I have a simple pyspark application which is running but I want to run its egg distributable instead of managing alot of .py files. As a starter application it only reads a file and display it.

Project Hierarchy is as follow:

```
DisplayStats
|
|__ src
|   |___ displayStats.py
|   |___ __init__.py
|
|__ __main__.py
|__ setup.py
```

Code of *main*.py:

```
from src import displayStats

if __name__ == '__main__':
    displayStats.showStats()
```

Code of displayStats.py:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder
               .master("local")
               .appName("gill")
               .getOrCreate()
df= spark.read.load('rootPath/fileName.csv', format='csv', header='true')
df.show()
```

Code of setup.py:

```
setup(name='displayStats',
      version='0.0.1',
      description='A sample PySpark application',
      author='Bilal',
      py_moudles=['__main__']
      packages=['src'],
      zip_safe=False)
```

Making an egg using:

```
python setup.py bdist_egg
```

And I get this single egg file:

```
displayStats-0.0.1-py2.7.egg
```

Now I want to spark-submit this egg file and I tried these two commands:

```
1) spark-submit --master local displayStats-0.0.1-py2.7.egg

I get this exception: 
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Cannot load main class from JAR file:/D:/displayStats/dist/displayStats-0.0.1-py2.7.egg
```

And if I give **Main class Name** in the command (I think **Main class Name** in only required if we have scala or java project because I dont have class in **main**.py):

```
2) spark-submit --master local --class __main__ gill-0.0.1-py2.7.egg

Command Prompt shows these 4 warnings but job is not submitted:
19/10/08 15:34:19 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

Please guide me in this scenario, I am able to run a job if I zip them but I want to run egg file. I have not found any solution on net.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not using the correct option, for python you should use `--py-files`.

```
spark-submit --master local --py-files  displayStats-0.0.1-py2.7.egg __main__.py
```

part taken from spark-submit help

```
--py-files PY_FILES     Comma-separated list of .zip, .egg, or .py files to place on the PYTHONPATH for Python apps.
--class CLASS_NAME      Your application's main class (for Java / Scala apps).
--name NAME             A name of your application.
--jars JARS             Comma-separated list of jars to include on the driver and executor classpaths.
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, I have even tried --py-files option but for this command we should have two files separately. .EGG file and a seperate __main__.py file. What I want is to attach egg with the cluster and tell it the module name in this case __main__.py to run. Like in scala we spark-submit the jar to the cluster and our main file is in the jar.

Comment: @BilalShafqat I don't think that's possible. it's how it's been implemented.

Comment: @BilalShafqat I am encountering this same problem, haven't found a solution yet. Looks like specifying a "separate" Python file is mandatory. Seems like very poor design.